# Print an XML file in the browser

Tags: php, xml

```
$xml = file_get_contents($exportedFile);
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
print($xml);
```

I am trying to very simply parse an XML file to string and display that string in the browser. This is the simplest way I could do it (without using DOM, SimpleXML obj., etc...).

The problem is that nothing is being displayed - just an empty white page. When I debug - the `$xml` variable contains the whole XML file contents, but then nothing gets printed.

**Update:**
I found the problem was in that there was an `<?xml-stylesheet...` node in the beginning of XML document, therefore trying to display the XSL sheet, which does not exist.

Comment: What if you view source?

Comment: Then I can see it, but I need it displayed in the page. Another way is if I just open it like `myaddress/file.xml` in the browser address bar, but I want to try outputing it.

Comment: Are there any empty lines or other content at the top before the xml?

Comment: this should definitely work from the code snippet you show. One way to improve it would be not load the file and assign it to a variable but instead change the print call to `readfile($exportedFile);`

Comment: I found the problem was in that there was an `<?xml-stylesheet...` node in the beginning of XML document, therefore trying to display the XSL sheet, which does not exist.

Answer (score -1):

Thing is, XML is encapsulated in HTML like tags, so the browser will not show them (try setting your browser to show source).

To amend this specific situation you can do the following:

```
echo('<pre>'.$xml.'</pre>');
```

Now, next up is to try and iterate through the tree, I suggest you take a look at the print_r function when you have a parse-tree as that function will give you a good understanding of your structure.

The pre tag tells the browser to turn off the parser and simply display the text.

So something like this can also be very helpful to your further endeavors.

```
echo('<pre>');
var_dump($xmlparsetree);
echo('</pre>);
```

https://www.php.net/var_dump

Comment: Do you have to view source to see this in your browser http://www.cnn.com/tools/search/cnncom.xml ?

Comment: Unless the XML is part of the HTML, it should be sufficient to send an appropriate Content-Type header

Comment: That strongly depends what he is going to do with it after processing it, if he want to represent it to the user in some nice way he definitely needs to do integrate it into his website.